# return result of palindrome check with for-loop in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am doing a palindrome-check assignment in Python. I have to use a for-loop to check if it is a palindrome or not.

I think that I am on to the right track, but I am having trouble returning the result of the loop. When running the program it always returns True, even when it is not a palindrome. I would really need help to see if I have done the for-loop correctly and how to return the correct result. 
My program as it is now looks like this:

```
def main (): 

    showResult(testPalindrome(newText()))

def newText():
    word = raw_input ('Hi, insert a word:')
    clean = (',','!','.')
    for i in clean:
        cleanedText = word.replace(i, "").lower()
        return cleanedText


def testPalindrome(cleanedText):
    testword = cleanedText
    list = [testword]

    for i in range(len(list)/2):
        if list[i] != list [-i-1]:  
            continue
        else: 
            break


def showResult(palindrome):

    if True:
        print 'Yes, it is a palindrome '
    else:
        print 'No, it is not palindrome'
```

main ()

Comment: `return True` / `return False`

Comment: where do i put this is the code?

Answer (score 1):

You never `return` anything from `test_palindrome`.  Remember that it is not a palindrome if *any* letters fail to match, but *all* must match to pass, so:

```
for i in range(len(list)/2):
    if list[i] != list [-i-1]:  
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Should become

```
for i in range(len(list)/2):
    if list[i] != list [-i-1]:  
        return False
return True
```

Also, to make your code more robust, you could replace `clean` with `string.punctuation` (remembering to `import string`).

Answer (score 0):

For testing is a string is a palindrome, compare it with its reverse.

```
In [1]: p = 'this is a test'

In [2]: p[::-1]
Out[2]: 'tset a si siht'

In [3]: p == p[::-1]
Out[3]: False

In [4]: q = 'racecar'

In [5]: q == q[::-1]
Out[5]: True
```